# How to get logcat messages/stack traces from an Android Wearable in DDMS

Tags: android, logcat, ddms, wear-os

I noticed that none of my Moto 360's logcat messages are showing up in my DDMS.  My wearable device doesnt show up in the list of devices either.

How do I get the logcat output from my wearable into Android Device Monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I didn't have the option enabled on the watch.  Below are the steps I had to do in order to get the logcat output to show up.

1. Go into the Android Wear app on the phone and enable `Debugging over Bluetooth`
2. Terminal command `adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444`
3. Go into `Settings` on the watch, go to `About`, and click `Build number` 7 times
4. Go into `Developer options` on the watch and enable `ADB debugging` (you should also enable `Bluetooth debugging` as well)

That's it!

A couple flaming hoops, but relatively painless. Hope this helps someone.